# What does "0x0 Transaction mined but execution failed" mean when attempting to deploy via Remix on Rinkeby?

Tags: contract-development, contract-deployment, remix, metamask, rinkeby

I am attempting to deploy a test contract on Rinkeby using Remix IDE and the MetaMask extension in chrome. However when I try to execute the contract I receive this message in the status section: "0x0 Transaction mined but execution failed".

What does this mean and what could be causing such a problem?

I appreciate any ideas on how to fix this error. Thank you.

Comment: This problem often occures when you don't provide enough ga to the deploy transaction or if the contract is too big and then goes beyond the gas limit of a block. You should provide the transaction hash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mined failed might be happen below conditions:

1. Might be low gas, because your method is required more gas,

   - Resolve:

     - All ways pass gas along with transaction. Don't leave to default gas, your method may require more gas to execute that method.
     - Don't hard code gas, because its depends on your input
     - Use `estimateGas()` function before execute call direct method. Then provide extra 10-20% gas.
2. Method is revert or assert() failed condition is failed.

   - Resolve:
     Write test cases and run those before deploy contract on mainnet.

Can you provide us transaction hash or code

Answer (score 0):

Most of the times the reason as mentioned is that the method runs out of gas. Increase the gas limit value for the contract and it should work.